# Angular API HttpClient Method definition clarification

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-httpclient

I'm reading through the documentation on Angular, trying to understand the syntax of the method definition of the ['post'](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) method for Angular's [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#httpclient) class, and I don't understand what the pipe implies in the definition.

Looking at the header or param definition here, it says:

```
  params?: HttpParams | { 
    [param: string]: string | string[]; 
  };
```

The full definition is:

```
post( 
  url: string, 
  body: any, 
  options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | {
     [header: string]: string | string[]; 
   }; 
  observe?: "body"; 
  params?: HttpParams | { 
    [param: string]: string | string[]; 
  }; 
  reportProgress?: boolean; 
  responseType: "arraybuffer"; withCredentials?: boolean; 
})
```

What does the pipe imply in this definition? I've googled it but there's not much on exactly what that syntax means, I'm new to angular so explanations are very welcome.

My best guess is that it works like an OR operator or something? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` introduces a union type as describe [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). This has the meaning that `params` can be either `HttpParams` or an object with all `string` or `string[]` properties (`{ [param: string]: string | string[]; }`)

Comment: Thank you! That answered it.